# Count the number of objects

Tags: matlab

I am given an assignment. The original image has circles and lines. I have already extracted lines and circles and stored them in a different image. Now, I have to count the number of circles and lines and write text on each on of them. But it has to be done using morphological operations.

```
   I=imread('circles_and_lines.png');
   SE4 = strel('disk',15);
   bw=imopen(I,SE4);
 OutputFileName = ['./output_images/'  'circle.png'];
  imwrite(bw,OutputFileName); 

 newbw= imsubtract(I,bw);
 OutputFileName = ['./output_images/'  'line.png'];
  imwrite(bw,OutputFileName);
```

Above is the code to extract circles and lines. But I am confused about where to go from here. How can I count these objects using just morphological filters

Comment: Use binary component analysis .

Comment: Use `bwlabel`..